# Small range of random numbers for float/double, good for integral types (C++, VS2010)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, random, numeric-limits

I am trying to use a template in VS2010 for random number creation based on type. I am using the code below:

```
template<class BaseT>
struct distribution
{ // general case, assuming T is of integral type
    typedef std::tr1::uniform_int<BaseT> dist_type;
};

template<>
struct distribution<float>
{ // float case
    typedef std::tr1::uniform_real<float> dist_type;
};

template<>
struct distribution<double>
{ // double case
    typedef std::tr1::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist_type;
};

template<class BaseT>
class BaseTypeRandomizer
{
public:
    BaseTypeRandomizer() : mEngine(std::time(0))
    {
    }
    void CreateValues(std::vector<BaseT>& Values, size_t nValues)
    {
        typedef typename distribution<BaseT>::dist_type distro_type;
        std::random_device Engine;
        distro_type dist(std::numeric_limits<BaseT>::min(), std::numeric_limits<BaseT>::max());

        for (size_t iVal = 0; iVal < nValues; ++iVal)
        {
            Values[iVal] = dist(Engine);
        }
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, creating objects of BaseTypeRandomizer for `char`/`int`/`long` etc. (integral types) returns numbers that cover the entire range, but for floats and doubles they don't. Floats all come between `1e+37` to `9e+38`, and doubles are `1e+307` to `2e+308` (or at least all are in that neighborhood). Checking the `dist` object in the VS debugger shows the limits there are correct, but the `Values` vector gets filled with a much smaller range of numbers.

Does anyone have an idea on why are the limits not working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating a value between `numeric_limits<T>::min()` and `numeric_limits<T>::max()`. But `numeric_limits<T>::min()` is probably not what you expect it to be: For floating-point types, it is the minimum **positive** normalized value, which is very close to zero. So your code can only get positive floating-point numbers. For `float`, this would be numbers up to about 3.4e38. The vast majority of these numbers are more than 1e37, so it makes sense that those are most of the results you get.

To get possible finite values, you'd need to use the range from `numeric_limits<T>::lowest()` to `numeric_limits<T>::max()`. But this would lead to undefined behavior because the size of the range passed to `uniform_real_distribution` must be up to `numeric_limits<RealType>::max()`.

So you'd need to generate the number in a different way. For example, you can generate a non-negative number between 0 and `numeric_limits<T>::max()`, and generate its sign separately.

Comment: So how can I use the full range for floats/doubles for random number generation?

Thanks,
Oren

Comment: @OrenSarid: My previous answer missed the real issue here. See my edited answer.